# Combination of DATESYTD but keep the month separete to get a avrage on a distinct employee of the accumulated months

Tags: powerbi, dax

This data

```
Row_ID  EmployeeID  Date
1              1    2023-02-13
2              2    2023-02-13
3              3    2023-02-13
4              1    2023-01-13
5              8    2023-01-13
6              7    2023-01-13
7              4    2023-01-13
8              5    2023-01-13
9              6    2023-01-13
```

and a **DATE** table

I use a Measure

```
_DistinctEmployee = DISTINCTCOUNT(tblTestEmployee[EmployeeID])
```

And a Messure for the DATESTYD

```
_DATESTYD = CALCULATE([_DistinctEmployee],DATESYTD(vwDimDatum[Datum2]))
```

[Image for date choise and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAB1G.png)

The end result i want on the measure *(NOT drag in MONTH in the table)*

Is that the datestyd take the distinct numbers of employee *(Becouse in the real scenarie there can be more then one employee that month)*
and then + that month with the next month and then + it to the next month thats accumulated
and then take al this addition of values and devide it with the number if the month thats choisen.

**Example of the data**

I have choisen MONTH Febuary
In my measure i get the number 8 and thats the distinct accumulated employees in JAN and FEB and if i devide that with the number of the month i get 4 and that wrong that no the avrage.

there is **3** distinct employee in January

and there is **6** Distinct employee in Febuary

**3+6 / 2(Febuary) = 4,5**

Thats the average of employees in al this month.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following measure:

```
=
VAR DateChosen =
    MIN( vwDimDatum[Datum2] )
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER( ALL( vwDimDatum ), vwDimDatum[Datum2] <= DateChosen ),
        vwDimDatum[Datum2],
        "Distinct Employees", [_DistinctEmployee]
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX( T1, [Distinct Employees] )
```

Comment: I get Null when i choose January, 6 when i choose february and 4.5 when i choose mars. I need to get 4.5 when i choose  february and 6 on january

Comment: i printed out the DateChosen to se what i gave and then I changed to MAX insted of MIN and it worked

Comment: see the <= and then added some data in 2022 and then i get the wrong values. DATESTYD is just accumulating the current year. Im trying to fix an AND statement so it will have YEAR(DeteChosen) = YEAR(vwDimDatum[Datum2]) not fixed it yet

Comment: After DAteChosen i added       && YEAR(vwDimDatum[Datum2]) = YEAR(DateChosen)

Comment: Pleace change your answer with the fix and i accept the check accepted answer

Comment: a Questian i have the real data and 
januari have 24 employees and februari have 25. Does this solution devide by days or Month.. BEcouse i get 24.47 as avragex..